# javascript if userlang is X onclick value is Y

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am actually facing issues regarding following script that is supposed to set the onclick value of the button depending on the userlang.

Any clue abt what I am doing wrong please?

Thanks, best regards.

```
<div class="button">
<button id="xx" name="xx" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" >button name</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var elem = document.getElementById("xx");
   elem.onclick = function () {
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
    if {var userLang = ":en" {
     elem.setAttribute("onclick", 
       "location.href='http://www.toto.com'");
    }}
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Please check the syntax of [`if` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else). Also, most likely `navigator.language` never returns ":en".

Comment: thanks teemu actually working on this else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the if condition and the parenthesis

```html
<div class="button">
<button id="xx" name="xx" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" >button name</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var elem = document.getElementById("xx");
   elem.onclick = function () {
   var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
      if (userLang.match(/^en/)) {
         window.location.href='http://www.toto.com';
      }
   }
</script>
```

`userLang.match(/^en/)` will match all the versions of english.

Comment: McRist very quick answer thanks. 
I was close with adding an else but could not figure out the correct language code... now its brilliant thank you so much!

Comment: for more specific you can use, regex `/^en/` that matches all versionof english

Comment: Thx en is great just dong the following now var elem = document.getElementById("xx");

elem.onclick = function () {
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 

if (userLang == "fr-FR") {
 elem.setAttribute("onclick", "location.href='http://www.tata.fr'");
 }
else {
 elem.setAttribute("onclick", "location.href='http://www.toto.com'");
 }
}